# How do I prevent Get-AzKeyVaultSecret from reading disabled Secrets?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I set up a key vault.  I created an application with Key Vault Secrets User.  I added the application to the key vault using Access control.  Everything is working great!
Then I disabled a key and there is no other version of this key available.  If I run the below command to get a list of secrets, I get an error on the one I disabled.

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName
```

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
Code: Forbidden
Message: Operation get is not allowed on a disabled secret.
```

How do I tell Get-AzKeyVaultSecret to ignore disabled secrets?
I read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultkey?view=azps-10.2.0 but It did not provide a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an **Azure Key Vault and added secrets** like below:

[image]

When I executed the same command, I got both enabled and disabled secrets:

```
Connect-AzAccount

Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName testrukkvv
```

[image]

**To fetch only the enabled secrets in the Azure Key Vault**, use the below command:

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName testrukkvv | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true }
```

[image]